# Setting the scoring parameter of RandomizedSeachCV to r2

Tags: python, keras, scikit-learn

I am trying to use `randomizedSearchCV()` from sklearn to find the best parameters to use in a neural network model build with keras. I would like for it to 'score' based on the r2 metric - it doesn't throw up any errors when I run, but after it has run it says best_score_ is -1.436.

This isn't a valid r2 metric (is it?). So I'm wondering if anyone can take a look at the code below and see if they can spot

a) What is this `best_score_` of -1.436?

b) How can I amend the below code to make the function return the `r2` metric?

My neural network model is called model4.
I have added "scoring = 'r2'" as a parameter in `RandomiszedSearchCV`, which I thought was meant to tell it to use this as the score

## This is the code I a using for the `RandomizedSearchCV()`:

```
model5 = KerasClassifier(build_fn=get_model4, epochs = 10)

params = {'num_layers' : [1,2,3,4], 'size_layers' : [5,10,25,100],'batchnorm' : [True,False], 'act' : ['relu','sigmoid','tanh'], 'lossfn' : ['mean_squared_error','mean_absolute_error','mean_squared_logarithmic_error'], 'lrate' : [0.01,0.001,0.0001]}


random_search = RandomizedSearchCV(model5, param_distributions=params, cv=KFold(3), scoring='r2')

random_search_results = random_search.fit(inputs,decisions)

print("Best: " + str(random_search_results.best_score_)+" using:"+str(random_search_results.best_params_))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the R^2 score can be negative, its not the correlation but the coefficient of determination, with a maximum of 1.0 and a minimum if minus infinite. You can get this information from the scikit-learn [documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.r2_score.html#sklearn.metrics.r2_score).

Comment: Oh! I see, I missunderstood - i thought it could range to -1. That's great news (although obviously my model is quite poor so far!) I'll keep trying to find a better model. 

Thank you so much for your quick answer!!